# Angular refresh current page - problems

Tags: angularjs

home.html is a template with two fieldsets.
I use ng-show to make the first fieldset visisble when the page loads and when a user clicks a button the other fieldset is made visible and the first one hidden.
This is accomplished by using a variable 'preview' like so (this is a jsfiddle) :

```
<div ng-app="app">
    <div ng-controller="MainController">
       <fieldset ng-show="!preview">
           <p>This is fieldset 1</p>
           <button ng-click="toggleIt()">Toggle</button>
       </fieldset>
       <fieldset ng-show="preview">
           <p>This is fieldset 2</p>
       </fieldset>
        <a href="#" ng-click="returnIt()">Home</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

and the controller is like:

```
    angular.module('app', []).
controller('MainController', ['$scope', function ($scope) {
    $scope.preview = false;  

    $scope.toggleIt = function(){
     $scope.preview = true;   
    }  
    $scope.returnIt = function(){
      location.reload();  
    }   
}]);
```

In JsFiddle it works fine but when I use the 'Home' link in my angular app which is:

```
<a href="/">Home</a>
```

and this is picked up by the app.routes.js file

```
.when('/', {
            templateUrl : 'app/views/pages/home.html',
            controller: 'MainController',
            controllerAs: 'main'
        })
```

Nothing happens -  fieldset 2 is still visible rather than fieldset 1.
I was expecting that `$scope.preview` would be set to false as this is the first line in the controller and that would make the first fieldset visible again.
When I do a browser refresh it works but not using the routing.
I have tried `location.reload();` (and this works in the fiddle), but when I apply it inside the app controller I get TypeError: `$location.reload` is not a function.

I have tried `$route.reload()` which sends it into an infinite loop, and `window.location.reload()` which keeps reloading.

Is there a simple way I can achieve a browser-like refresh of the page via the routing?

Comment: Js fiddle link is missing. You are using `$route` without injecting in controller.

Comment: the jsfiddle was actually working with location.reload() - I was trying to explain that actual app wouldn't work with location.reload or $route.reload and yes the actual app controller does inject $route and $location otherwise its same as fiddle plus the separate routes. The fiddle is https://jsfiddle.net/8bvzgg4n/

Comment: @meanstacky Try with $route.reload() or $window.location.reload() which is applicable for your case.

Comment: Have you tried $scope.preview = false;  in your returnIt function?

Comment: @ParthaSarathiGhosh I have tried $route.reload() and $window.location.reload() the former loops infinitely the latter reloads constantly. In my actual code I'm using <a href="/">Home</a> so unfortunately I can't use $scope.preview = false in returnIt - that was just for the jsfiddle (which works fine).

Comment: I think in that method where you are calling $route.reload() is also being called at the time of Controller Initialization. So it is being called as infinite loop. Put a debug pointer in that like $route.reload() and check first time while you page load it is being called or not, also check call stack. If it is being called you need to re think your logic.

Comment: Are you using `$locationProvider.html5Mode(true)`?

Comment: @tasseKATT thanks, but yes I do. I think I will have to rethink the logic like '@ParthaSarathiGhosh' said as it appears to be in conflict with the controller initializing.